# How to change port of tomcat from eclipse's tomcat plugin

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I am using `Eclipse Kepler` and `EclipseTotale`'s tomcat plugin. I am using `Oracle XE` at port `8080`, and want to run Tomcat at port `9090`. I have changed `server.xml` and changed the port at this line :

```
 <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
redirectPort="8443"/>
```

It still says the address is already in use. Also, I am a little skeptical as to whether changing `server.xml` will have any effect as I have selected **Context Decalration Mode** to be **Context Files** instead of **server.xml**

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Which server.xml did you change, one in the Servers project?

Comment: actually, I changed the one in the tomcat home directory..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It worked after changing `server.xml` in tomcat's home directory. The problem was that there were multiple instances of tomcat that were running. I changed the ports of other connectors too.. that may also have had an effect, though I am not sure.

Comment: Eclipse seems using own server.xml file, so this does not work (or at least does not work on Mars). The correct answer is below by @Anuj Sharma. Probably need to sacrifice a point of reputation for downvoting ...

Comment: Administration Permission denies me to change the Port in Server.xml

Answer (score 39):

Just double click on the server listed in Eclipse. Here It will display Server Configuration.
Just change the port Number like from 8080 to 9080. and start your server. Dialog box will appear to save the changes. Click yes and server will start.
Hope it'll help you.

For details refer; 
                 [link](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-change-port-numbers-for-tomcat-in-eclipse)

Comment: This is the second time this has helped me in about as many days.  It's frustrating that if you *right click* on the server and click "Properties" you get almost nothing you can configure, but double clicking the server gives you a window full of configuration options.  I keep forgetting to *double click* the thing.

Answer (score 9):

Open Eclipse
Get Server view form Window -> Show View -> Servers
Then double click the tomcat server
Configuration window open and you can change the ports there.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is, first you change server.xml in Tomcat master folder then you delete the Tomcat folder from Eclipse Project Servers folder then you can recreate Server in Eclipse again.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple and  Easy way.

**No config or pom change or anything required. go to Run -> Run configurations... -> click the tab (X)=Arguments then give the argument as follow.**

```
-Dserver.port=9099
```

****Once you click Run configurations.. you may have to select your app under Java Application, if not selected.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse to run the Spring boot application, then you can also go Run -> Run Configurations and then Arguments tab.

Here you can put the VM arguments -Dserver.port=8080 as shown below:
[image]

Read more: https://www.java67.com/2019/07/spring-boot-3-ways-to-change-port-of-tomcat.html#ixzz7J9Hbnvrx

Answer (score -1):

open eclipse, 
now double click on server(that you added in your workspace),
open server.xml and
using (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) search for 8080, now change it here 8080 to 9080, save it, now you can run your application

Comment: Administration Permission Denies