# Form in HTML with Java and the Servlet is giving me an error

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets

I have this simple form in HTML  (index.html)

Then I have my Java file (ServletExample.java) and my configuration file web.xml.

When I open the Index.html it seams to work

[image]

But when I click the submit button I get the following error.

Can please anyone help me out to find what is the error?

Please see all the code for all the files below.

THANK YOU!!!!!

ERROR:

[image]

HTML CODE

```
<HMTL>
<body>
<form action="servlet1" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have my Java file (ServletExample.java)

```
package org.example02.test;

import java.io.IOExcetion;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class servletExample extends HttpServlet{
protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest reg, HttpSevletR
     throws ServletException, IOException {
   String name = req.getParameter ("name");
   String name = req.getParameter ("lastname");

   resp.getWritter().println("<html>");
   resp.getWritter().println("<body>");

   resp.getWritter().println("Your name is:" + name);
   resp.getWritter().println("Your Last name is:" + lastname);

   resp.getWritter().println("</body>");
   resp.getWritter().println("</html>");
     }
 }
```

And my configuration file: (web.xml)

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>


 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>Test2</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.example02.test.ServletExample</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<display-name>Example02</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the double quote `"` in your action, add it and close the form tag:

```
 <form action="servlet1" method="get">
 ...
 </form>
```

Comment: I fixed those 2 issues but still getting the Error: "The request URL /Java/servlet1 was not found on this server"

Comment: Might be related to the port 80 not being open? If so, then how to open it? Thanks

Comment: @Samuel go to your application server and see the right port

Comment: Abdelhak, thank you much for the suggestion. Could you please let me know how to do so? I'm very junior and don't know who to do so. Thanks

Comment: @Samuel Try to see [this](https://techteam.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/changing-the-tomcat-port-settings-in-eclipse/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615907/how-to-change-port-of-tomcat-from-eclipses-tomcat-plugin)